# How to calculate used memory for php-fpm?

Tags: php, fpm

Suppose I have a php application that runs with php-fpm. Below are the options for php/php-fpm and opcache. How can I calculate how much memory is used by all of the components?

```
memory_limit=128M
...
opcache.memory_consumption=128M
...
[www]
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 2
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 2
```

Here is my thinking. php-fpm is starting 1 process with 128 MB and opcache 128MB = 256 MB. If php-fpm creates a new server/process we will have 2 processes with 256 MB and opcache 128 MB = 384 MB. Is that correct?

The background is to calculator the correct memory limits for a Kubernetes deployment.

Comment: The memory limit does not mean the memory taken, it means the memory that could potentially be taken, and that is per "request" (running script) so if an FPM process is (somehow) handling more than 1 request concurrently then it would potentially take more memory. Again, those are maximums not absolute values.

Comment: @apokryfos yes, I understand that. Maybe my question wasn't clearly stated from me. I want to calculate the maximum memory that php can claim for itself. As I understand the php-fpm documentation, `pm.max_children` is how many requests php-fpm will handle simultaneously. So, my calculation is correct?

Comment: I would think so.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about how much memory the app uses, you can use something like
`ps aux | grep -P "fpm|COMMAND"`

Once you have that, 10MB for e.g., you know how many MB your FPM thread is using.  This is your child.

Next you need to know how much memory your server is using.  Open `htop`, sort by mem (`shift + m`), take all your top mem usages above 1MB, which are not php related, add them up, thats your current server usage (non php).

If you can load your server when you check this that helps, particularly if your running mysql, that uses alot of memory, so helps if you load your server a bit there when you do your check.

If you find for e.g. your 8GB server uses only 512MB mem, you can reserve some extra space for it, say 750MB, or 1GB.  that leaves the remaining 7GB to divide by your app mem usage. `10MB/7GB` = `700` threads/childs.